# SQL - Query what lies within the first three weeks of a current month

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I get a result that lies within the first three calendar weeks of the current month.
I tried to use use `DATEPART` but didn't succeed.

```
SELECT
    ,DELIVERY_DATE
    ,MONTH(GETDATE()) AS ACTUAL_MONTH -- Get the current calendar week of the DELIVERY_DATE
FROM DELIVERY_TABLE
WHERE DELIVERY_DATE --.. is within the first three calendar weeks of the actual month
```

Comment: Do you mean by deliverydate within first three week of current month?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Answer (score 1):

```
SET DATEFIRST 1 -- Define beginning of month--
SELECT [...]
AND DELIVERY_DATE >= dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate())) 
AND DELIVERY_DATE <  dateadd(day, 22-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT
,DELIVERY_DATE
,MONTH(GETDATE()) AS ACTUAL_MONTH -- Get the current calendar week of the DELIVERY_DATE
FROM DELIVERY_TABLE
WHERE DELIVERY_DATE>=DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DAY(GETDATE()), GETDATE())
AND DELIVERY_DATE<=DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DAY(GETDATE()), GETDATE())+20
```